# How to wrap org.json4s.JValue in org.asynchttpclient.Response

Tags: java, scala, json4s, asynchttpclient

I'm refactoring some tests where previously the response was parsed into `org.json4s.JValue`

I want to pass the response as type `org.asynchttpclient.Response` as input parameter. In order to distinguish the HTTP code status.

`NettyResponse` and `WebDavResponse` are implementations of `org.asynchttpclient.Response`.

How to wrap `org.json4s.JValue` into the body of `org.asynchttpclient.Response` ?

Comment: Not familiar wih these types especially but sounds like you need to convert your `JValue` to string representation and fill the body of your `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

The key solution when you cannot set the data of the instances. **Mock them**.

Here, I use Mockito. Add the dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>x.x.x</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In Scala

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.when

  @Test
  def GivenXThenAssert(): Unit = {

    val jsonStringResponse: String = ""
    // instantiate the class Response
    val httpResponse = Mockito.mock(classOf[org.asynchttpclient.Response])
    // stub the implementation method
    when(httpResponse.getResponseBodyAsStream()).thenReturn(new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonStringResponse.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))

    // THEN
    //
    val processedResponse = process(httpResponse)
    assertEquals(....)
    }
```

Notice I stubbed the method `getResponseBodyAsStream`. Why not another ? Because the **asserted** function `process` calls this previous method.